# How to create GitHub Enterprise Server - service connection In Azure DevOps using rest api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to create GitHub Enterprise Service - service connection using azure DevOps rest api.

I found this rest api in Microsoft Docs -

POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4)

When I create service connection manually It asks me for url , connection name and GitHub token

[image]

How Can I pass this in json ?

What Json Data do I need to use for creating service connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture the request body by pressing F12 while you manually create GitHub Enterprise Server service connection. After pressing "Verify and save", it's supposed to get the request body under **Network** tab. Check my following screenshots, I have circled the useful part:

[image]

[image]